# Cómo configurar www

Tags: web, godaddy

¿cómo se puede configurar para que el sitio web inicie con "www"? He intentando con cada "explicación" asociada, pero no resulta.

Tengo el dominio en GoDaddy y el servidor en Apache 2.4 (XAMPP). Probé con modificar el archivo vhosts, los valores de CNAME, etc.

Comment: No me queda claro, tenes un XAMP en GoDaddy con acceso a los archivos de vhosts?

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que requieres es que tu página siempre sea redirigida con el `www`, no necesitas alterar ninguna configuración de tu dominio en GoDaddy. De hecho, si lo haces sin conocimiento, podrías descomponer todo y provocar que tu sitio web se caiga.

Por otro lado, esto lo logras con un archivo `.htaccess`, el cual, dependiendo de tus necesidades, vas a usar. De manera básica, vamos a poner como ejemplo que tenemos dos urls, una con `http` y otra con `https`.

> El archivo .htaccess debe de ir incluido en el archivo raíz de tu proyecto

Con `http`

1. http://tupagina.com

El código `.htaccess` sería:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^tupagina\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.tupagina.com/$1 [R=301]
```

Con `https`

2. https://tupagina.com

El código `.htaccess` sería:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^tupagina\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.tupagina.com/$1 [R=301]
```

Ahora, si entras a tu web y dependiendo de qué código `.htaccess` se haya adaptado a tu necesidad, vas a poder ver que te va a redirigir siempre al `www` que siempre has querido, si es que entras, claro, al sitio sin el `www`.